# why does this batch command which counts the number of lines in a text file work?

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f %%a in ('type "file.txt"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a count=%%a
```

I found this command here http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.CountLines

It seems to work, but I can't figure out why.  I'm reluctant to use something which I don't understand, unless it has a bug for special characters etc. but I can't figure out why it works.

Comment: Type `find /?` from a command prompt and read what the `/v` and `/c` switches do.

Comment: How familiar are you with batch? The answer will be smaller if I don't have to explain what a `for /f` loop does.

Comment: Unwind the command. `type "c:\windows\win.ini" |find "" /v /c`

Comment: It would help if you told us what part it is that you don't understand.  If you don't understand `for`, we have a problem.

Comment: Well, one angle could be this: I didn't understand it either, and then I noticed it's *batch*, not *bash*.

Comment: Confused as to why you just didn't ask the question on the DosTips Forums if you got the code from DosTips.  Always baffles me when people do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside out

- `type file.txt` simply read the file and output its contents to standard output.
- In this code, the output of the `type` command is piped into a `find` command.
- The `find` command reads it standard input (no file to read has been indicated) and filters it, searching for lines that does not contain (`/v`) nothing (`find` will not match anything if a empty string is indicated). While filtering, it will count how many lines are found and will output to standard stream only the number of matching lines (`/c`). As the empty string does not match anything but the `/v` switch negates it, we end matching (and counting) all the lines in the file.
- The two previous piped commands are executed using a `for /f` command. `for /f` is used to process a string, read the contents of a file, or execute a command and process its output.

*note*: by default the command to be executed is enclosed in single quotes in the `in` clause of the `for /f` command

*note*: the pipe is a special character and to include it inside the `for /f` command we need to escape it (`^|`)

- For each line (the string, each line inside the file or each line in the output of the command) the code inside the `do` clause is executed, with the line being processed (or some parts of it) stored in the `for` replaceable parameter (`%%a` in this code)
- The output of the `find` command (the number of lines in the file) is stored in the `for /f` replaceable parameter, the `do` clause is executed and the number of lines in the file (stored in the replaceable parameter) is copied into a environment variable

*note*: the `set /a` is used for arithmetic operations. It is not necessary in this case and a simple `set` command should do the work, but maybe it was written this way to make it clearer that the value that will be stored in the environment variable is a number

Comment: *"maybe it was written this way to make it clearer"* - Yes, or to force it into being a number (0) if the output is, for some reason, not numeric.

Comment: @GolezTrol, environment variables are always strings, the `/a` just invokes a separate parser to handle arithmetics, something not present in this code. I still have not seen a `find /c` command output anything that numbers, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, environment variables are always strings, but `set /a var=XYZ` results in var becoming `0`. So you could use `/a` here like a typecast, guaranteeing that var will contain a 'number' (a string containing a valid numeric value), instead of the textual value `XYZ` which may break a next step. It could be used as a safeguard or as a way to easier check the outcome in a next step. Usually it should work, but I can imagine that `find` may return something else in case of an error (file unreadable, network timeout, etc).

Comment: Ok, a quick test shows that this should indeed always work and `type "file.txt"^|find "" /v /c` will return an error, followed by 0, when the file is not found, so maybe this safeguard isn't necessary after all. But maybe the author of that code didn't know that. ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol, `find` outputs errors to stderr (not readed by the `for /f` command). There is no possibility of a file error from `find` as it is not reading any file but piped data. If the full inner command fails and there is no output the `do` clause is not executed and the variable is empty (there is not any initialization) or a string that matches another variable could be retrieved and generate a wrong value, or it can generate a math error, fail and not initialize the variable,... there are ways in where it could fail, but `set /a` does not *ensure* no failure nor is *needed* here.